# Jquery UI Slider set value dynamically on sliding the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery slider , If I slide the slider,In slide function 
I will test certain scenario . If the scenario is not satisfied the slider should be positioned back to its original position .

**For example :**

The current slider value is 1 and the user slide it to value 2, in slide: function (event, ui) function I'm checking the condition if not satisfied the value of the slider should be reverted back to value 1 .

So that I have used the code in else part

$("#slider").slider({ value: parseFloat(return_slider_value) });
 $("#slider").slider('value', 1);

It is not setting back the value 1 still it shows the value 2 in the slider.

My requirement is the value of slider value should be dynamically changed .

```
var slider_Value = $.trim(data.details.merchant_table_booking_hours);
if (slider_Value == '') 
{
  slider_Value = 0;
}
var return_slider_value = slider_Value;
$("#slider").slider({
value: slider_Value,
min: 0,
max: 12,
step: 0.5,
slide: function (event, ui) 
{
    var selected_button_count = 0;
    $(".time_slot_buttons").each(function () 
    {
        if(this.attr('selected-id')==0)
        {
            selected_button_count = parseInt(selected_button_count)+1;
        }
    });
    if (selected_button_count>0)
    {
        if (parseFloat(ui.value) != 0) 
        {
            $("#slider-value").val(ui.value);
            $("#show-slider-hrs").html(ui.value + " hrs ");
        } else 
        {
            $("#slider-value").val('');
            $("#show-slider-hrs").html('');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please Select a Floor And Timing Buttons" + return_slider_value);
        $("#slider-value").val(return_slider_value);
        $("#show-slider-hrs").html(return_slider_value + " hrs ");
        $("#slider").slider({ value: parseFloat(return_slider_value) });                                                                 
        $("#slider").slider('value', 1);
    }
}
})
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: can you try after setting the value back: `$('#slider').trigger('change');` OR/AND
`$('#slider').trigger('slidechange');`

Comment: @CalvinNunes Could you brief a bit more please .

Comment: in your else statement, after this part: `$("#slider").slider('value', 1);` add the two lines of code that I posted in my last comment.
Also, if it doesn't work, try to set the value like this: `$( ".slider" ).slider( "option", "value", 10 );`

Comment: @CalvinNunes I have tried all your three options but none works . 
$('#slider').trigger('change');
 $('#slider').trigger('slidechange');
$( ".slider" ).slider( "option", "value", 10 );
On the else part

Comment: Well, it was just a shot in the dark... I don't know what it can be then... Can you edit your question and add a working snippet including the jquery UI library (use the `<>` button to do this). with an example working snippet would be much better to try to help

Comment: @CalvinNunes sure will create a snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you will see from the API documentation on jQuery UI Slider (http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/), the slider can be read and set the following way, after initialization:

```
// Getter
var value = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value" );

// Setter
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value", 10 );
```

**EDIT:**

The answer might possibly depend on the value that you return to the `slide` event.
Consider this code.

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
      value: 1,
      min: 0,
      max: 12,
      step: 0.5,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        //Evaluate condition
        var condition = false; //or true
        if (!condition)
            return false; //Canceling the event will prevent the handle from moving and the handle will continue to have its previous value.
        else
            return true;
      }
    });
});
```

Full [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/EliteSystemer/k26yapLh/).

Canceling the `slide` event will prevent the handle from moving and the handle will continue to have its previous value.

Comment: This is the correct syntax. If it still doesn't work, please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank You  return false;  Cancel's the event